# How would u reduce this lambda calculus

Tags: nlp

How u reduce this ?

VP = λx(Ǝe (closing(e) ^ closed(e,x)))(λQ(Ǝx(Restaurant(x)^Q(x))))

i got something like

Ǝe(closing(e) ^ closed(e,λQ(Ǝx(Restaurant(x)^Q(x)))))

But im not sure if this correct or not